# Automated my builds

Tags: android, maven, ant, build, jenkins

I have multiple app and android project that I want to be automated in their build and release sequence. I already have ant script to build and create the apk of all my app. Now I want to have only one script or ant file that will start all the build sequence for all the app. 
Maybe I just don't konw where to search, but I can't find some easy documentation on ant.

The point of all this is to use jenkins with ant (or maven, I'm not sure of the difference between them for now) to automated all the build sequence when people commit on the project.

Any int will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven will also help with your dependencies (over ant) so you don't need to pass around jars. I would recommend Maven over ant any day. As the syntax is and overall process is easier to understand, but at the end of they are both build tools. If you are able to, I would more recommend upgrading to gradle.  It is very easy to create different build types and create them all with `./gradlew assemble`

Here is a project from Jake Wharton where you can see the power of gradle. There is a release and a debug build, but you can make a lot more if you would like. https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020

Here are the Android Docs for gradle http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide. If you can't find what you are looking for here, also check out the main gradle guide http://www.gradle.org/documentation

If you can't upgrade to use gradle let me here back and I will dig up some info on Maven / Ant for you.

Comment: Thanks for that, i'll read this documentation to see if gradle is ok with my set up.

Comment: This solution looks way more easy and well more documented than the other. So I can just use it with jenkins, I don't need to use maven or anything else?

Comment: Yup! I have it setup to just run `./gradlew assembleDebug` instead of creating the release but if you run `assemble` it will build them all (`./gradlew tasks` will show you all the options). I also recommend always using the gradle wrapper so you don't have to deal with updates and the like.  This works best with Android Studio which is steal in early access preview, but I think it's about as stable and more useful than eclipse.